# ember.js render partial on any template

Tags: ember.js

I need to pick up an ember.js project to finish a few things. Unfortunately I don't have time to learn the whole framework and features but I was wondering how I create a partial.

I read the documentation below but don't really understand what goes where. I presume the second block of text goes in the .hbs template but where do I put the top block so that the second block can be rendered on any .hbs template?

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='_author'>
      Written by {{author.firstName}} {{author.lastName}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='post'>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <div>{{body}}</div>
      {{partial "author"}}
    </script>
```

Comment: ember js require introduction to some new concepts. If you have a very tight schedule that you cant devote time to learn it, i suggest dont use it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I didn't add the partial to:

```
EmberHandlebarsLoader.loadTemplates([])
```